# Php login does not work properly

Tags: php, authentication

below is my simple login.php code, I created a user with

> usermail: admin userpass: admin123

But whenever I try to login with admin account, it ignores the if statement and it opens the homepage.php, what might be the problem, thank you.

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password") or die("Could not connect to the database");
 mysql_select_db("nisbet", $connection);
 error_reporting(0);

if($_POST['login']){
 if($_POST['usermail'] && $_POST['userpass']){
     $usermail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usermail']);
     $userpass = mysql_real_escape_string(hash("sha512",$_POST['userpass']));
     $user = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `usermail` = '$usermail'"));
     if($user == 0){
         die("User does not exits <a href='index.php'>&larr; Back</a>");
     }
     if($user['userpass'] != $userpass){
         die("Incorrect password! <a href='index.php'>&larr; Back</a>");
     }   
     //die("You are now logged in as $usermail !");

     if($user['usermail'] == 'admin' && $user['userpass'] == 'admin123'){
         header('Location: adminpage.php');
     }else{
         header('Location: homepage.php');
     }
 }   
}
```

Comment: firstly, this doesn't help you `error_reporting(0);`. turn it "on" and display it.

Comment: *"it ignores the `if` statement"* - which one? you have five.

Comment: The stored password appears to be hashed but your condition checks for the unhashed version.

Comment: oh the if at the bottom, if its admin; open adminpage.php else open regular homepage.php

Comment: You don´ t seem to be storing the logged-in state so I could imagine that your admin page redirects automatically to your home page as there is no valid login / session set.

Comment: but I also tried to get the password before I hashing it and the result is the same

Comment: personally,  I wouldn't spend too much time with this. Using deprecated `mysql_` functions and a sha family. use prepared statements and `password_hash()`. this is old technology. there are many already-made scripts out there, using a much safer method.

Comment: thank you for your help guys, Benoit's comment solved my problem

Comment: @GokhanBurak If that works, what is to stop someone from opening `adminpage.php` directly?

Comment: you re right, its only a local thing I'm trying to implement and only I know the password of the admin

Comment: @GokhanBurak: jeroen is saying that no password is needed to access the admin page, since anyone can enter "adminpage.php" in the URL.

Comment: well, nothing I can say about, it just a simple database and no protection is needed for now :)

Answer (score 1):

The `$userpass` variable contains a hash of the submitted password, so comparing it to "admin123" won't work.

You should compare it to the hash of "admin123" instead, or not comparing them a second time since you've already done that before in your code.

Comment: thank you sir, you re right, I fixed it now it works pretty fine

Comment: @GokhanBurak: you should read other people's comments very carefully: there are other problems in your application that should be fixed for security reasons.